# SFMC Sender Authentication Package - subdomains

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

a business unit within our corporate group would like to use their existing global domain for sending out emails and, additionally, have a bunch of different sub-domains to be used by different country offices in the business unit. Since email deliverability is not my strong suite, I was wondering can we get a SAP for their global domain (let's call it XYZ-global.com), and afterwards set up a number of different Sender Profiles with each having its own sub-domain attached to the global domain XYZ-global.com for which we had bought the SAP? For example, the Netherlands Sender Profile would have a sub-domain NL.XYZ-global.com, while French would be France.XYZ-global.com, is that feasible? If yes, are these sub.domains first being set up by the domain administrator and then sent to us in MC to include in the respective Sender Profiles? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine doing so - however there are few considerations to keep in mind:
One business unit can only have one SAP domain, so to add additional domains, you must purchase additional Private Domains in your contract.

Additional domain must be in/under the same domain name, for DMARC compliance.
Example: SAP domain: XYZ-global.com / Private domain: NL.XYZ-global.com
This will comply with DMARC because both are under “XYZ-global.com”

Note: Don’t just make up sub-domain names. If XYZ-global.com is the SAP domain, and you want to add “NL.XYZ-global.com” -- it must be set up as private domain. It will not just “automatically work” because the top level domain is hosted by Salesforce, as there is no sub-domain/domain “inheritance” with SAP or Private Domain.

You will also need to set up these in your DNS, and delegate them to Salesforce by pointing the NS records for them to:

- ns1.exacttarget.com
- ns2.exacttarget.com
- ns3.exacttarget.com
- ns4.exacttarget.com

[As described here.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subdomain_delegation_guide.htm&type=5)

Comment: Great answer Lukas! One additional clarification: when you say under the "Note" paragraph: "If XYZ-global.com is the SAP domain, and you want to add “NL.XYZ-global.com” -- it must be set up as private domain." you mean that it has to be set up as "private domain" within Salesforce, or "set up" in this case means that these subdomains have to be purchased 'outside' Marketing Cloud? As I said, this part is not my strongest suit, so please don't mind if this questions sounds silly.

Comment: You need to purchase the number of Private Domains with Salesforce, as needed. This covers only the license cost. Additionally you should create the needed subdomains on your DNS server, and delegate them to Salesforce. No additional costs of purchasing domains are connected to this last step.

Comment: I see, so registering additional private (sub)domains in an SFMC business unit imposes additional costs from Salesforce alone.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @LukasLunow this thread was most applicable to my current issue. I am setting up SAP with 1 domain (@email.company.com). I want to use the same dedicated IP and SAP domain across multiple BUs. I also want to set up additional from email addresses in the BUs for specific sender profiles. Do those need to be private domains or can I just use any domain I need for this sender profiles? Second part of that is, what if those additional from emails are a subdomain off the original SAP? Sorry just some confusion on me end.

Comment: @Heavy2 you can use same SAP (and dedicated IP) across multiple BUs. You can create any from-addresses as long as they use your SAP domain. From-addresses on different domains would require you to purchase a private domain, as you otherwise wouldn’t send authenticated emails.

Comment: Thank you @LukasLunow much needed!